# php, json SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1

Tags: php, json, apache, firefox, curl

test.php

```
  <?php

  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $urlPaczkomaty =  "http://api.paczkomaty.pl/?do=listmachines_xml";
  $curl = new Curl\Curl();
  $curl->get(  $urlPaczkomaty  );

  $xml = simplexml_load_string($curl->rawResponse);
  $json =  utf8_encode (  json_encode($xml)  );
  $arrList = json_decode($json, TRUE);

  $fieldsToOut = array(
      'name',
      'type',
      'postcode',
      'province',
      'street',
      'town',
      'latitude',
      'longitude',
      'paymentavailable',
      'status'
  );

  $key = "machine";

  if( empty($arrList[ $key ] ) ){
      throw new \Exception( "no key" );
  }
  $out = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach( $arrList[ $key ] as $item  ){
      foreach(  $fieldsToOut as $field ){
          if( empty( $field  )  ){
              die( 'iii' );
          }
          if( empty($item[ $field ]) ){
              die(" no key: ". $field. "  in = ".( empty($item[ 'name' ]) ? '' : $item[ 'name' ] )  );
              $item[ $field ] = 'xxxxx';
          }
          $out[ $i ][$field] = $item[ $field ];
      }
      $i++;
  }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($out);
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php-curl-class/php-curl-class": "^4.10"
    }
}
```

In firefox, when I execute (debian, apache):
http://test.loc/test.php
I receive the folowwing errors (not the same):

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 129650 of the JSON data

or

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 261200 of the JSON data
```

in my local enviroment i.e. xamp, windows 10 work without errors.

Any suggestion?

Best regards
Robert.

Comment: First I would suggest passing `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` to `json_encode`. This will give you formatted JSON so you can get something more useful than "column 261200"... After that, have a look at the JSON that's being read, specifically the indicated line in the (updated) error message.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

I deleted the addon (plugin) in firefox, that parse json.

Robert